# How can I tame my 5 year old's wild hair?

Tags: hair

My daughter has some seriously crazy hair. She has waves right around her face. When she starts playing and getting sweaty, her hair will start sticking out and just look horrible and I can't figure out what to do with it. I tried letting her have bangs, but as they grow out they start flipping out to the sides. I have her bangs growing out and the hair still sticks out to the sides!

I don't feel right putting a bunch of products in her hair because she is only 5, but I feel bad for her because when I look at the other girls her age, their hair seems so manageable and smooth.

Can someone give me suggestions as to how I can tame the beast that is my daughter's hair?

Comment: UPDATE: After Sabrina took her bath on Tuesday, I used detangling spray and the next morning her hair wasn't as wild. The waves around her face are still there, but at least now they aren't as frizzy and wild. :) Thanks for the suggestions. She loves wearing headbands to get that crazy hair out of her face when she eats too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like this is more your problem than hers.  She is probably to young to care and doesn't compare her self to others the way we, as mothers, do.

In terms of recommendations, you need to be careful not to send your uncomfortable feelings about her hair to her.

Try headbands, elastic bands, or clips (if she will keep them in).  I find, as you did, that bangs don't usually work.

Comment: We use headbands pretty much every day. I try to put her hair up when I can but because it is fine, the wavy parts fall out and continue to look crazy. Do I just let her hair grow out super long in hopes that once it is heavy enough, the crazy wave/curls will get tamer?

Comment: +1 for not letting your uncomfortable feelings transfer to your daughter.

Answer (score 5):

Despite your challenge of managing her hair, she must look adorable!

**Talk to your preferred hairdresser.** Ask specifically for tricks that don't involve hairspray.

Did you know that there are different shapes of cross-section, and that this determines not just how curly the hair gets but also how well it lends itself to different treatments and hairdos? Neither did I! Hairdressers are professionally trained to deal with lots of different kinds of hair, and a good one can help you with tricks and advice that we common folk have never heard of :-)

Answer (score 3):

Even though you said you don't want to use product, I have found detangler spray very useful.  It takes a lot of the stress out of brushing her hair, but doesn't leave a residue like hairspray or gel.

Plaits worked well too.

Comment: Good idea. I will have to sit her down sometime and see if she will let me put braids in her hair. I have detangling spray, but I always forget to use it! Hopefully that will keep some of the static out of her hair too :O)

Answer (score 3):

My two daughters both had incredibly crazy hair which would not stay in bunches or plaits as it is so fine. The two pronged solution:

- Detangler - to at least make their hair brushable
- Allowing it to grow - the eldest's is now long enough it sits flatter. The youngest still has mad hair, but having a 5 year old with mad blonde curls is actually pretty cute

(offtopic - especially on a trampoline, which acts like a Van de Graaff generator!)

But in general - don't worry about it - she is 5. Lots of time before she'll start being concerned about how she looks to boys :-)

Comment: I did catch myself saying to her this morning that her hair was crazy. After I said it I reminded her that crazy hair or not she is still a pretty girl and she had a huge smile after that.

Answer (score 3):

My daughter has curly hair which does tend to get a bit on the wild side. So as others have already suggested I use a detangler spray. I make it up from a small amount of leave in conditioner mixed with water in a pink sparkly spray bottle. I find it's better to brush it wet as it then dries into nice curls or waves rather than brushing it when it's dry as it just goes frizzy.

Curly and wavy hair tends to be drier, so you might find it beneficial to use a conditioner when you wash her hair (so much for the not using product!) Helps keep those nasty knots away and tames the frizz.

Make a bit of a fuss about doing her hair and let her choose what style/ what colour hair bands etc.